# How do you declare a type alias in a f# constructor?

Tags: f#

```ml
type Entity =
    abstract member newEntity: Entity
    abstract member clearEntity : Entity
    abstract member lastEntity : Entity
    abstract member loadData: Entity
    abstract member saveData: Entity -> unit
    abstract member deleteData: Entity -> unit
```

Is there any way to avoid repeated writes Entity word?

```ml
type Entity =
    type T = Entity
    abstract member newEntity: T
    abstract member clearEntity : T
    abstract member lastEntity : T
    abstract member loadData: T
    abstract member saveData: T -> unit
    abstract member deleteData: T -> unit
```

I want an implementation like this, Scala should be able to do it

Comment: Just for the record - this is not very idiomatic way of writing F#. It looks like you're trying to implement something in a way in which someone would do it using an OCaml module system. F# is a mixed FP and OO language, so if you need this kind of extensibility, OO idioms might do a better job. (Of course, it's hard to say from your synthetic example, but it does not look like very nice F# code to me...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put a type declaration inside another. What you can do is make mutually recursive type declarations:

```
type Entity =
    abstract member newEntity: T
    abstract member clearEntity : T
    abstract member lastEntity : T
    abstract member loadData: T
    abstract member saveData: T -> unit
    abstract member deleteData: T -> unit

and T = Entity
```